# Setup of firebase-admin sdk in javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My end goal is to get user email, using user's id. So far I figured out I need to use the firebase admin SDK. Right now I have this code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://zdajtotestdb.firebaseio.com"
});

export default admin;
```

The serviceAccountKey is the file I downloaded from my firebase project here (Sorry it's in Polish)

[image]

I tried using this video as a tutorial/reference

https://youtu.be/WtYzHTXHBp0

And right now, when I try to do anything I get this in the npm start console:

> 20:22-48 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> ```
>    ./node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
> 32:12-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
>    ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in '/home/iron/Documents?>/Projects/zdajto-admin-panel/node_modules/hash-stream-validation'
> ```
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
>           To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

And this in the browser console:

> Error fetching user data: Error: "Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse access token response: Error: Error while making request: XHR error. Error code: undefined"."

What am I missing?

Comment: You might find it a lot easier to set this up using Firebase Tools - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Admin SDK is not available for Javascript, here the prerequisites:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#prerequisites

So, for example, you cannot operate as admin in a web page for security reason, but only in a privileged environment (like a server).

I'm creating a web administration interface for my project, where admin operations are performed in Cloud Functions.

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing. Thanks for the info

Comment: I hope to be helpful to someone else!