# Firebase list all users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use the firebase admin sdk but when I try to do this: `admin.auth()` it gives me an error saying Error:
*The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services*
The app is already initialized when I use the normal sdk, how to I initialize the admin-sdk so I can list all users?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

The Admin SDK is designed to be used in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. It is specifically not designed to be used in client-side code, as doing so will gives any user of your app privileged access to your entire Firebase project.

If you want to show a list of users in your app, the two common approaches are:

- Store the necessary information about the users in a cloud database (such as Cloud Firestore, or Realtime Database) and read it from there, using the server-side security rules of the database to ensure users can only access information they're authorized for.
- Wrap the necessary calls from the Admin SDK in a custom server-side API that you create (for example, on a server you control, or in Cloud Functions), using the custom code to ensure users can only access information they're authorized for.

Also see:

- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password)
- [Can't retrieve list of all users from firebase authetication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513390/cant-retrieve-list-of-all-users-from-firebase-authetication)
- [ReactJS and Firebase Users Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423265/reactjs-and-firebase-users-admin)
- [Setup of firebase-admin sdk in javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183423/setup-of-firebase-admin-sdk-in-javascript-file/52641826)
- [Firebase list all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903927/firebase-list-all-users)

Comment: None of the links you provided have good, date-related (= version related) answers. One of those is actually to a JAVA question (not JAVAscript) You actually linked inside your answer to this page.

Comment: Sorry you found this answer not useful @Sagive. If you're still struggling to list all users from Firebase in your JavaScript code after reading the linked answers, it might be best to post a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck, rather than downvote an answer that apparently was useful to others *when* they were looking for how to implement that use-case. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯